# Remove-Item -Recurse -Force can't remove symlinks

Tags: powershell, symlink

It seems that `Remove-Item -Recurse -Force` cannot deal with removing symlinks. How do I recursively delete everything from a given directory with symlinks made all over the place?

MWE:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test> mkdir foo
    Directory: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        7/30/2020  11:58 AM                foo

PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test> mkdir bar
    Directory: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        7/30/2020  11:58 AM                bar

PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test> New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path foo -Name bar -Value C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test\bar
    Directory: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test\foo
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d----l        7/30/2020  11:59 AM                bar

PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test> Remove-Item -Recurse -Force foo
Remove-Item : There is a mismatch between the tag specified in the request and the tag present in the reparse point
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-Item -Recurse -Force foo
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Remove-Item], Win32Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The actual CMD equivalent to `Remove-Item -Recurse -Force` is:

```
cmd /c rmdir /s /q foo
```

as it will delete symlinks also in subdirectories. This seems to be good enough for me.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are running into the same issue as mentioned here:

https://github.com/powershell/powershell/issues/621

And workaround which is mentioned in this thread is:

```
Get-ChildItem $somepath -Attributes ReparsePoint | % { $_.Delete() }
```

Or you can gather more information here:

https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/11331

Comment: @liori if you add `-Recurse` to `Get-ChildItem`, maybe.

Answer (score 2):

There's always cmd.  Wmi and powershell can't even delete profiles these days because of links.

```
cmd /c del bar
```